# Disable Flutter's "red screen of death"

Tags: error-handling, dart, flutter

Is there a way to disable Flutter's "red screen of death"?
I don't mind it during debug, but it seems to also appear in production builds - and I can't find any information about how to disable it, or catch the error myself.

I tried catching stray errors with `FlutterError.onError` and `runZoned(onError)`, but both did not stop the red screen from appearing.

For reference, I'm talking about this screen:

[image: rsod]

Comment: You have to make sure that your app runs without errors, e.g. never return null from a `build` function.

Comment: @boformer well, that's the goal, yes - but certain errors are out of my hands (like, the scroll-listener failing in certain situations), and I'ld still prefer to be able to handle things myself if something is overlooked. The red screen of death is pretty pointless, since it only confuses an user instead of allowing me to do something like an alert with a clear message like "an unexpected error occured".

Comment: You can edit the Flutter source code to display something else (e.g. blank white screen). The code is in your Flutter installation directory.

Answer (score 19):

You could override ErrorWidget.builder method.
I'm resolved this.

・Example code.

```
void main() {
    ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Container();
    ...
}
```

・Default code

```
static ErrorWidgetBuilder builder = _defaultErrorWidgetBuilder;
```

I hoped its your help.

---

2019 12 21 updated

Or Change ErrorWidget backgroundColor and textStyle.

・Example code

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
void main() {
    RenderErrorBox.backgroundColor = Colors.transparent;
    RenderErrorBox.textStyle = ui.TextStyle(color: Colors.transparent);
}
```

Comment: Isn't this overriding with the same as it does by default? Disabling would be by returning `Container()` instead of `ErrorWidget(details.exception);`

Comment: I believe this is what I need, but where can I find ErrorWidgetBuilder.builder?

Comment: ErrorWidgetBuilder.builder is static.
Please see this source.
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/eb9160eb93b726a325f708be6e8a928757e85da5/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/framework.dart#L3757

Comment: Sorry. My sample is not good. Please run
void main() {
    ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails details) => Container();
}

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use Catcher which is a free flutter plugin which catches and handles errors in Flutter application. Catcher offers multiple report modes and handlers to cooperate with Flutter applications

just add catcher in your pubspec.yaml

`catcher: ^0.1.2`

For more info about catcher 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/catcher

A nice tutorial to get started with catcher https://medium.com/flutter-community/handling-flutter-errors-with-catcher-efce74397862

Answer (score 1):

```
void main() {
 bool isDev = true;
          ErrorWidget.builder = (FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails) {
            return AppErrorWidget(
              errorDetails: errorDetails,
              isDev: isDev,
            );
          };
}          

    class AppErrorWidget extends StatelessWidget {
      final FlutterErrorDetails errorDetails;
      final bool isDev;
      const AppErrorWidget({
        Key key,
        @required this.errorDetails,
        this.isDev = false,
      }) : super(key: key);
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Material(
          child: SafeArea(
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all(color: Colors.red)),
              child: ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    height: 20,
                  ),
                  Text(isDev ? errorDetails.toString() : '')
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. You can use the [edit] button to improve this answer to get more votes and reputation!